# evaluate the improper integral from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^4+1}dx$$

Do I use Cauchy's Integral formula?

Comment: Hint : Use Residues calculus.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Why? $x \to \frac{1}{y}$ works ways better.

Comment: @Elliptic Curve Yes. But since op wants to use cauchy integral formula, so I suggest Residues calculus will be a good choice.